# Windows phone create side menu bar like Facebook

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, user-controls

I am new to Windows Phone 7 development and I'm trying to create side menu bar like the one used on Facebook.

I have created `usercontrol` and added buttons for different screens, I have also created `PhoneApplicationPage` and added a button.

When I click on that button, it will try to slide from top to right like menu bar.

If I click it again, at the top right button it will hide it.

If anyone can help, please share your code or examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I've just blogged a complete solution for this... and indeed you need Visual States!
http://depblog.weblogs.us/2013/07/22/facebook-like-settings-pane-windows-phone/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: kleopatra... true, but the total solution is to large as response in StackO. Overall the idea was already given by stating to use Visual State Manager, I'm only pointing to a working downloadable project.

Comment: @Depechie It's fine to link to the complete solution on your blog, but at least include enough of the information here so that even if your blog goes away tomorrow, it would still be a somewhat useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `SlideView`, described as "... navigation drawer inspired by the official Facebook app on Windows Phone." https://slideview.codeplex.com/

Edit
Once you have installed SlideView through nuget's install-package SlideView

Create a UserControl that will represent the SlideView you want, say LeftView.xaml. You can create another user control for the other side, say RightView.xaml

Then in your App.xaml file, define the SlideView as a resource,

```
xmlns:slideView="using:SlideView.Library"
xmlns:views="using:SideNav.Views"
xmlns:local="using:SideNav">

<Application.Resources>
    <slideView:SlideApplicationFrame Header="SlideView" Background="White" x:Key="RootFrame" >
        <slideView:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
            <views:LeftView/>
        </slideView:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
        <slideView:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>
            <views:RightView/>
        </slideView:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>
    </slideView:SlideApplicationFrame>
</Application.Resources>
```

Once done Edit your App.xaml.cs to change the default RootFrame and th OnLaunchedMethod

```
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    private TransitionCollection transitions;

    public static SlideApplicationFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {

        RootFrame = Window.Current.Content as SlideApplicationFrame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (RootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            RootFrame = this.Resources["RootFrame"] as SlideApplicationFrame;

            // TODO: change this value to a cache size that is appropriate for your application
            RootFrame.CacheSize = 1;

            // Set the default language
            RootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = RootFrame;
        }

        if (RootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // Removes the turnstile navigation for startup.
            if (RootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
            {
                this.transitions = new TransitionCollection();
                foreach (var c in RootFrame.ContentTransitions)
                {
                    this.transitions.Add(c);
                }
            }

            RootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
            RootFrame.Navigated += this.RootFrame_FirstNavigated;

            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            if (!RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

This should work.. Just add content to the Rightview.xaml and LeftView.xaml.
For some Reason my WindowsPhone 8.1 xaml crashed when I launched it. But everything worked when I used the Zumicts Fork of SlideView which is available as a nuget package here

```
Install-Package SlideView.Library.WP81.Zumicts
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not an easy way to do that like iOS. But you can use [Visual State Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Basically, Shape a bigger screen than your stage. Then, you need to create a state which will shift your screen a little bit left in the stage and you can use a button. You need to call the state on button's on click method.

PS: Do not use storyboard. Use the States it is easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try side menu bar like facebook also with gesture support. try the link below.

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Control_animation_while_navigating_between_panes_inside_a_Windows_Phone_page