# Setting ListBox Height in Windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can i set suitable size for listbox in Portrait Or Landscape views automatically ?

I don't have any problem in portrait view : 
[image]

But in landscape view the listbox height is not okey , and listbox has not to be on recordpanel.
[image]

this is my xaml code :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#E9E9E9" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FEFEFE" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <MediaElement Name="SoundPlayer" AutoPlay="False" Volume="1" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">

        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelTopBar" >
        </StackPanel>

        <phone:Pivot  Height="40" Background="#F9A11D" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" >
            <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Alle"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="A-E"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="F-J"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="K-O"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="P-T"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="U-Z"/>
        </phone:Pivot>

        <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxAlphabet" Height="Auto">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:RoundButton Tag="{Binding File}" Content="{Binding Label}" FontSize="30"  ButtonHeight="90" ButtonWidth="90"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="#FFD0D2D3" Foreground="White" PressedBrush="#F9A11D" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" Click="RoundButtonAlphabet_Click" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="RecordPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,8">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="100">
            <userControls:SoundRecorderPanel></userControls:SoundRecorderPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think making [Application Side Menu][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985415/windows-phone-create-side-menu-bar-like-facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood right, but if you want that record panel is on the alphabets and alphabets-list is scrollable, then I can help.

The reason why alphabets-listbox is on the record panel, is that you put listbox to the stackpanel. And stackpanel is on the grid row, which height-property is auto. If you want that record panel is on to alphabets, you should define your row definition like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

But then of course listbox doesn't fit to the screen and you have to scroll list if you want to see all alphabets.

Edit: You have to also change the stackpanel, where listbox and pivot is, to the grid like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelTopBar" Grid.Row="0" >
        </StackPanel>

        <phone:Pivot  Height="80" Background="#F9A11D" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
            <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Alle"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="A-E"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="F-J"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="K-O"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="P-T"/>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="U-Z"/>
        </phone:Pivot>

        <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxAlphabet" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="2">
        // and so on...
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for help . with a little bit changes and your help my problem has been solved .