# slide or side panel Control in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am looking for a control which could allow me to slide (I don't know that control) and I have seen that control in Onefootball application (located at the top left of page) in wp8 store.

The control allow the user to click on a button (I don't know if its button or not) and a panel slide from left or right you then perform some action and then click on the button and the panel swipes back.

[image: You see icon left to BARCELONA]
[image: This screen slides from left]

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the `Slide-View` panel which looks similar to the `Facebook` app?

[SlideView : a Facebook-like panel for Windows Phone](http://cyril.cathala.org/Blog/2014/03/09/slideview-a-facebook-like-panel-for-windows-phone/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985415/windows-phone-create-side-menu-bar-like-facebook)

Comment: Thanks, I already saw that control but I want something which I find in Onefootball app.

Comment: If you could post an image of it?

Comment: So the one which i posted is similar to what you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

That's called the hamburger button/icon/menu, you can have the [SlideView](http://cyril.cathala.org/Blog/2014/03/09/slideview-a-facebook-like-panel-for-windows-phone/) control like @Kilasangar mentioned, but here's a new one that looks similar to the one you posted above :

[image]

Download its source code and demo [here](http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2015/2/1/slide-in-menu-control-for-windows-phone)

Comment: Thanks! I think this and slideview could be the same. in fact this is what I'm looking for, unfortunately, this doesn't provide a hamburger button. I have modified some of the options according to my requirement, but I couldn't figure out to place a button at top. Let me mention that I have swipe (gesture) event in my page, therefore I only want that user should click on humberger button to open this panel.

Comment: Well those two solutions are the only ones I could find, try to modify the source code to customize it as you like